# Does zero chemical potential implies zero lowest energy level for non-interacting quasiparticle excitations?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, bosons, chemical-potential, quasiparticles

Many of the quasiparticle excitations in solids have non-conservative particle numbers. Examples are phonons, magnons, excitons etc. Therefore, as many posts put, the chemical potential should be zero. **My questions is, does this imply that the energy spectrum of the excitations cannot have the form $E(k)=\Delta + Ak^2$?** Here, $k$ is wave number and $\Delta,A > 0$.

Since the zero chemical potential means adding or removing a particle does not change the free energy. If the excitations have lowest energy $\Delta$, it seems there will be a cost to add or remove an excitation. Unless, the entropy is also increased by $\Delta/T$ so that the free energy $F=U-TS$ is unchanged.

Or maybe, writing $E(k)=\Delta + Ak^2$ means the zero point energy is $\Delta$, so that the chemical potential should be $\Delta$ instead.

I am confused with the two point view. Which one is correct? For simplicity, assume the quasiparticles are non-interacting.

Edit:
I am now more comfortable with the first point of view, which is, although quasi-particles have non-zero energy, adding or removing one won't change the free energy of the system.